# circular struct in ctypes, python

Tags: python, c, struct

How to represent circular `struct` in python using `ctypes`?

A linked list can be represented in the following way in c

```c
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* next;
};


struct LinkedList
{
    Node* start;
    int length;
};
```

How to represent the same `struct` in python using `ctypes`.
I tried the following

```py
from ctypes import *


class Node(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("value", c_int),
        ("next", pointer(Node))
    ]
```

But the above gives the following error

```
NameError: name 'Node' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the documentation of [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types), there you will find this:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class cell(Structure):
...     pass
...
>>> cell._fields_ = [("name", c_char_p),
...                  ("next", POINTER(cell))]
>>>
```

### Something more

---

To reference a `class` inside a method you can do this:

```
# Don't do:
class Node:
    Node
# But:
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        type(self)
```

---

When you want to use type hints for a class from inside itself, you have to do this:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```